# Buddypress user registration validation not working with custom select query

Tags: buddypress

I have created a phone number as Buddypress Profile field. I need to check that no two or more user accounts share the same phone number. My query below is not enforcing the restriction.

I need help to resolve this.

```
function bp_phone_number_validate() {
   global $bp;
   global $wpdb;

  // check if phone number is in use
  $result=$bp->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$bp->profile->wp_bp_xprofile_data} WHERE value = '{$_POST['field_2']}' GROUP BY id;");

  if($result > 0){
    $bp->signup->errors['field_2'] = __( 'Phone number is already in use.', 'buddypress' );
  }   
}
add_action( 'bp_signup_validate', 'bp_phone_number_validate');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `$bp->get_var`.  Try using `$wpdb->get_var`.

Or try this:

```
function validate_user_signup($result) {
   global $wpdb;

   $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE value = '{$_POST['field_2']}'");

   if( $result != NULL ){

      $new_error = new WP_Error();

      $new_error->add( 'field_2', __( 'Phone number is already in use.', 'buddypress' ) );

      $result['errors'] = $new_error;
   } 

   return $result;
}
add_filter('bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'validate_user_signup', 10, 1);
```